# SyntaxError when trying to handle errors with except

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax-error, try-catch, except

I'm trying to program a personal assistant for my ICT class. I'm a beginner in python and I tried following a tutorial but I get a `SyntaxError` when using `except`.

This is the script:

```
try:
    command = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print ('Your command was: ' + command + '/n'
    #loop back ca sa asculte pentru comenzi daca nu gaseI'ste recon speech
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    assistant(myCommand())
```

And here's the error:

```
File "/Users/dumitruvictor/Desktop/Assistant.py", line 31
    except (sr.UnknownValueError:
         ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Operating System: Mac OS X

Comment: Count the number of parentheses, they should match...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: And please format your code properly. Python indentation is important!

Comment: Looks to me like you are missing a closing `)` on the statement `print ('Your command was: ' + command + '/n'`. These kinds of error messages can be misleading because the problem often has occurred elsewhere in the code—i.e. **not** actually the place that's causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot,that fixed the problem,but when i fixed it i ran into this problem can you please help me?                                                                            this is the error that python displays : unindent does not match any outer indentation level and it's location is next to unknown value error                  Thanks a lot! -Tudor @martineau

Comment: RedBeast: It's very difficult to tell since I can't see your revised code—but it sounds like an indentation problem. The `try` and the `except` have to be at the same level of indentation. Also, make sure you aren't mixing tab and space characters when indenting lines because they aren't equivalent in terms of the _amount_ of space they're considered to be adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the parentheses and indent the line after the `except`:

```
  except sr.UnknownValueError:
      assistant(myCommand())) # close parentheses, indent this line
```

Comment: In Python certain statements need to be indented. You can read more about Python indentation [here](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3).

Comment: Indenting a line means putting space before it.

Comment: No problem, you can mark the answer as correct if it helped.

Comment: I will mark it as correct but it says i can only do that i 5 minutes Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Hi,I succesfully got past that error but i started getting this one,can you please help me:  unindent does not match any outer indentation level      the error is located next to UnknownValueError: